# How to combine two dictionaries? One dict as key, another dict as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
Dict0 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}

Dict1 = {0 : {'a0' : 0,'a1' : 1,'a2' : 2},
         1 : {'b0' : 0,'b1' : 1,'b2' : 2},
         2 : {'c0' : 0,'c1' : 1,'c2' : 2}}
```

I would like to get a combine dictionary `CombDict`, which uses keys of `Dict0` as the values for `CombDict`, and uses values of `Dict1` as the keys for `CombDict`

```
CombDict = {{'a0':0,'a1':1,'a2':2}:'a',{'b0':0,'b1':1,'b2':2}'b',{'c0':0,'c1':1,'c2':2}:'c'}
```

I know it's very basic. My logical code is written, but definitely is wrong.

```
CombDict = {}
for k0, v0 in Dict0:
    CombDict.values()= k0
    for k1,v1  in Dict1:
        CombDict.keys() = v1
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.
Btw if you want to make the dictionaries more sense to you, just edit them.

Comment: Dictionaries can't be keys

Comment: Your `Dict1` keys are not valid; dictionaries are mutable, thus not hashable and won't work as keys.

Comment: I see. Thank. How about I change `Dict 1`, seems It takes now, how about combining clause, what should I use?

Comment: It is also far from clear how `Dict0` and `Dict1` relate to one another. How are keys from `Dict0` to be paired up with the keys from `Dict1`? The same value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, they are paired up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because dictionaries are mutable, you cannot use dictionaries as keys of another dictionary or store them in a set.

You'll have to capture an immutable 'snapshot' of the dictionary instead:

```
def dict_to_key(d):
    return tuple(sorted(d.items()))
```

Provided the dictionary values are not mutable either, you can use the return value of the `dict_to_key()` function as keys instead.

Now you can build the combined dictionary:

```
CombinedDict = {dict_to_key(Dict1[v]): k for k, v in Dict0.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> Dict0 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> Dict1 = {0 : {'a0' : 0,'a1' : 1,'a2' : 2},
...          1 : {'b0' : 0,'b1' : 1,'b2' : 2},
...          2 : {'c0' : 0,'c1' : 1,'c2' : 2}}
>>> def dict_to_key(d):
...     return tuple(sorted(d.items()))
... 
>>> {dict_to_key(Dict1[v]): k for k, v in Dict0.items()}
{(('b0', 0), ('b1', 1), ('b2', 2)): 'b', (('a0', 0), ('a1', 1), ('a2', 2)): 'a', (('c0', 0), ('c1', 1), ('c2', 2)): 'c'}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. Any doc link to explain this `{dict_to_key(Dict1[v]): k for k, v in Dict0.items()} `

Comment: @Shengen: it is a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays).